# How to enable LibGDX networking manually?

Tags: java, networking, server, libgdx

I'm using LibGDX to make a multiplayer game with a client and server. However, my server isn't a LibGDX application as my desktop launcher, so LibGDX doesn't get enabled automatically.

All I need is to create a server socket using Gdx.net.newServerSocket() but since LibGDX has not been enabled, Gdx.net is null. How can I enable it manually for my server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable LibGDX's networking manually, just set this before using anything from LibGDX networking API:

```
Gdx.net = new LwjglNet();
```

Even if the class is named "LwjglNet" the doc states: `it could be reused in other Desktop backends since it doesn't depend on LWJGL.`

Answer (score 0):

Try:
GdxNativesLoader.load();
That is what I use in my stand alone server

Comment: I get a GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'gdx64.dll' for target: Windows 7, 64-bit. However, my client starts LibGDX just fine.

Comment: I moved my Server launched to my desktop module, I don't get any exception anymore from loading library but Gdx.net is still null.

Comment: Does the server have the libgdx libraries as dependencies? It was a couple of years ago I did this myself but I simply put the server in the libgdx desktop project and I do not start the server as a LwjglApplication It is a standard Java application so before any calls to libgdx classes are done I simply call GdxNativesLoader.load(). I am also running Win7 64bit by the way.

Comment: As I said, moving my code to the desktop module fixed my dependency thing. However, Gdx.net is still null and there's no code in GdxNativesLoader.load() (I checked) that assigns a value to Gdx.net so it' not what I need. Plus I don't need natives libgdx libraries, all I need is their wrapper around java.net. I posted as an answer the solution to my problem.

Comment: OK, I think I read through this question a bit too fast then ;) I use Kryonet for networking mostly and for that this solution worked.